Kickr Thru axle compatibility
I have a 2018 Wahoo Kickr V4, which is currently set up for Quick-Release. I've just ordered a second-hand Orro Venturi (think it is a 2023 model?).
Will I need to buy the thru-axle adapter kit to get the new bike on the trainer? I think I still have everything the trainer shipped with originally?
Also is it safe to use the thru axle that comes with the bike for indoor training? I'm aware this isn't best practice with quick-release skewers as they can bend, however haven't seen this discussed for thru-axle bikes.
